# Show a div / element just when you go on the view of the element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide an element (a chart) and I want to show it only when I'm in the view of the element.

This is the code:

HTML chart:

```
   <section id="skills" class="skills-section">

        <div>
            <h1>MY SKILLS</h1>
        </div>

<ul class="chart" id="chart-line">
  <li>
    <span style="height:5%; background: rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.80);" title="ActionScript"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:70%; background: rgba(204, 51, 51, 0.80);" title="JavaScript"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:50%; background: rgba(255, 186, 2, 0.80);" title="CoffeScript"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:75%; background: rgba(0, 153, 102, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:90%; background: rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:15%; background: rgba(204, 51, 51, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:40%; background: rgba(255, 186, 2, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="height:55%; background: rgba(0, 153, 102, 0.80);" title="HTML"></span>
  </li>
</ul>   


    <div class="button-down">
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#projects"><button class="button-down-text">TESTO</button></a>            
    </div> 
    </section>

    <!-- Projects Section --> <!-- This is the begin of the section below -->
    <section id="projects" class="projects-section">
```

CSS chart:

```
.chart {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  /*max-width: 700px;*/
  height: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 2%);
  background-size: 100% 50px;
  background-position: left top;
}
.chart li {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 200px;
}
.chart span {
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: block;
  /*background: rgba(209, 236, 250, 0.75);*/
  animation: draw 1s ease-in-out;
}
.chart span:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 5px 1em 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: attr(title);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

JS for hide the element:

```
        $(function() {
    var oTop = $('#chart-line').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    var oBottom = $('#projects').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    var chartHidden = true;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        if ((pTop > oTop) && (chartHidden)) {
            chartHidden = false;
            start_count();
        } else if (pTop < oTop) {
            chartHidden = true;
        }

    });
});
```

I want to show the chart only when I scroll on it, I would like to hide the chart when I am in the view above the chart.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are doing anything with your `chartHidden`. Try changing your chart's css with jQuery.

```
var chart = $("#chart-line")[0];

// when chartHidden = false, do something like this
$(chart).css("display", "none");
```

Comment: But the reason why I want to hide the element is that I want to charge the amination of the chart just when I'm on the view of the chart. If I change the css, tha animation won't wait to charge.

Comment: @Matteo, It will if you place `$(chart).css("display", "none");` in the `if` statement after your `chartHidden = false`.